# Implement a "join" with a variety of tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have three tables:

**Materials**:

1. ID
2. Title
3. Content

**Likes**:

1. ID
2. MaterialID
3. UserID
4. IsLiked

**Visitors**:

1. ID
2. UserID
3. MaterialID
4. Date
5. ReadNow

I would like to get an object like:

1. Title
2. Content
3. CountLikes
4. CountVisitors

I tried to do the following:

```
from mat in ctx.materials
let visitors = mat.VisitorsCollection.Where(x=>x.ReadNow).Count()
let likes = mat.LikesCollection.Where(x=>x.IsLiked).Count()
let iliked = mat.LikesCollection.Where(x=>x.UserID == myID && x.IsLiked).Any()
select new {
   Material = mat,
   Visitors = visitors,
   Likes = likes,
   Liked = iliked
}
```

I get a selection of materials and separately the Entity Framework receives data on the number of visitors and so on.

I also tried the following:

```
from mat in ctx.materials
join lik in ctx.Likes.Where(x=>x.UserID == myID && x.IsLiked) on map.ID equals lik.MaterialID 
select new {
   Material = mat,
   Liked = lik.Any()
}
```

but now an error occurs:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Any()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: Try if `ctx.Likes.Any(x=>x.UserID == myID && x.IsLiked)` works.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, if I make LikesCollection.Any (...) then nothing will change, I will receive many individual requests.

Comment: What is the question/issue? The first query looks the EF intended/recommended way of doing joins. Client evaluation / N + 1 queries? Please update the post. Also specify the exact EF Core version because it really matters.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the answer. I answered the answer of Herald. Please, I wrote there what the problem is. The problem is that I have additional data that I have indicated above. As a result, I get 100 requests instead of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using entity framework, consider to use the ICollections, instead of performing the joins yourself.

You have a sequence of `Materials` where every `Material` has zero or more `Likes` and zero or more `Visitors`, both one-to-many relations, using a foreign key to `Material`.

If you've followed the [entity framework code first conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you'll have classes similar to the following

```
class Material
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Title {get; set;}
     public string Content {get; set;}

     // every Material has zero or more Likes (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes {get; set;}

     // every Material has zero or more Visitors (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Visitor> Visitors {get; set;}
}
```

Likes and Visitors:

```
class Like
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public bool IsLiked {get; set;}
     ...

     // every Like belongs to exactly one Material, using foreign key
     public int MaterialId {get; set;}
     public virtual Material Material {get; set;}
}

class Visitor
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     ...

     // every Visitor belongs to exactly one Material, using foreign key
     public int MaterialId {get; set;}
     public virtual Material Material {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to detect the one-to-many relationships. It might be that you want different table names, or different identifiers for your columns. In that case attributes or fluent API is needed

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, etc)

Once you've got your class definitions correctly, your query is simple and very intuitive:

Requirement:

> From my collection of Materials, give me from every Material, the Title, the Content, the  number of Likes it has and the number of Visitors it has:

```
var result = myDbContext.Materials
   .Where(material => ...)            // only if you don't want all Materials
   .Select(material => new            // from every Material make one new object
   {                                  // containing the following properties
       Title = material.Title,
       Content = material.Content,

       // if you want any information of the likes of this material, use property Likes
       LikeCount = material.Likes
           .Where(like => like.IsLiked)  // optional, only if you don't want all likes
           .Count(),
       NrOfVisitors = material.Visitors
           .Where(visitor => ...)        // only if you don't want all visitors
           .Count(),
   });
```

In words: from my complete collection of Materials, keep only those Materials that ... From every remaining Material, make one new object:

- Title is the title of the Material
- Content is the content of the Material
- LikeCount is the number of Likes of this material (that have a true IsLiked)
- NrOfVisitors is the number of Visitors of this material (that are ...)

Entity framework knows your relations, and knows that a GroupJoin is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem was that I did not receive data on a separate field, but received data on the entire object. Tell me, is it possible to get around this somehow? I am afraid that in the future when I have quite a lot of fields, I will forget to include them in this query and thus I will lose important data. And it’s normal that I have an extra table for every dependent table in "select"?

Comment: Oh my! too many questions for a comment. About the problem of missing properties. The original authors of design patterns posed that you should "design for change", If you let all your users communicate with the database directly, you will get problems after changes. Design a Facade-pattern (google for it), and let that be the only access to your database. Instead of Select new ..., use Select new MyFacadeClass. If your requirements change where you need different properties, you'll only have to change this face class code, and one test for your new requirement

Comment: Thank you for your help! Another small question. :)
And what about the accompanying tables? One-one-many relationship is of particular interest.

Comment: Google nor I don't known one-many-many relations. Did you mean many-to-many? google and you will find

Comment: I have a table with various images. The image table is related to the material table. So it turns out for me, Material->Images->Different sizes

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have foreign keys in the database then the EF would generate links between the objects so all you need to do is:

```
var result = ctx.materials.Select(x => 
     new SomeClass{
          Material = x,
          Visitors = x.Visitors.Where(v => v.ReadNow).Count(),
          Likes = x.Likes.Where(y => y.IsLiked).Count(),
          Liked = x.Likes.Where(z => z.IsLiked && z.UserID == myID).Count()
     }).ToList();
```

The syntax maybe is not totally correct, but you get the point ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This query also returns many additional queries for each row in the database.

Comment: I've added a filter for Visitors.ReadNow. 
What additional queries does it returns and what exactly do you need?
I'll try to fix it for you